# How to define while loop result in a global variable and use it in another function to process another task

Tags: php

I am trying to get first name and last name from a text file with while loop and store it in a global variable to which i want to access from any other function to echo all the first and last name in two different keys.

Here is my full code.

```
<?php 

OutputNames();

function ReadNames()
{
    $myFile = new SplFileObject("all/names.txt");

    while (!$myFile->eof()) {

        $row = str_getcsv($myFile->fgets());

        $first = $row[0];
        $last = $row[1];        
    }
}

function OutputNames()
{
    echo $first." ".$last;
}

?>
```

Comment: you must define $first and $last golbal in functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (or at least the part you've shown) really makes very little sense.

1. You're not actually using any global variables at all, so the `$first` and `$last` variables in each function are only in scope within those functions.
2. You never call `ReadNames()` anywhere, so it's not clear if it's ever being executed at all.
3. `ReadNames()` never returns any values, so the `$first` and `$last` variables simply cease to exist when the function ends.
4. The `while` loop in Readnames overwrites the `$last` variable every time it loops, instead of appending to it. But even then it wouldn't make sense because you'd end up with a list of first names and a list of last names, with no link between the first/last names which originally belonged together. A multidimensional associative array would make more sense to store the data (prior to displaying it).
5. Globals are generally a poor way to transfer information around your application - it's easy to get confused, have scoping issues, have things get overwritten, or cause conflicts between different parts of the code. Returning values from functions, and/or encapsulating functionality and data structures within objects are more reliable, testable and maintainable approaches.

It's not clear what actual flow you wanted / intended, but *maybe* something like this makes more sense?

```
OutputNames();

function ReadNames()
{
    $myFile = new SplFileObject("all/names.txt");
    $data = array();
    
    while (!$myFile->eof()) {

        $row = str_getcsv($myFile->fgets());

        $data[] = array ("first" => $row[0], "last" => $row[1]);
    }

    return $data;
}

function OutputNames()
{
    $results = ReadNames();
    
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      echo $result["first"]." ".$result["last"]."<br/>";
    }
}
```

It depends at what point in the process you actually want to do the reading from the CSV file, and whether you want to do it once and then re-use the results repeatedly, or what. If the code above doesn't resolve the issue fully, you'll need to clarify the exact requirements.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation, I am a beginner in the field, but your example achieved what I wanted actually